# Testing with create react app and Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app, autodesk-forge

I am using Autodesk Forge Viewer (v7.37) in a create react app (v4.0.2) and Typescript.
When I run the command `npm run test` I got the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: Autodesk is not defined at:

 export default class AssetListPanelExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel {
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which approaches did you try the solve your problem? Did you delete and reinstall the dependencies? Maybe tried a different version of Autodesk?

Comment: The autodesk forge viewer is not added with a dependency but imported in the html scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the reference scripts?

```
<!-- Autodesk Forge Viewer files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, Yes I am adding the reference scripts with specific version number:
`<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.37/viewer3D.min.js"></script>`